# Is it illegal to exercise or sunbathe nude on your publicly visible balcony?

Tags: england-and-wales

I suppose there are no public nudity laws unless it is done in a sexual spirit to make it indecent exposure.

One would be visible from the street as well as to one's neighbors. If they object perhaps then it is anti social behaviour or statutory nuisance?

Then what if children could see would that make it different if there wasn't a school nearby? How far would the school have to be?

Comment: Also how is this changed by the fact that you are in fact on your own private property?

Comment: A neighbour of mine had a complaint against her like that. Someone came to investigate. They found that she was visible if you climbed into the neighbours loft, opened the loft window, and leaned out dangerously far...

Comment: @gnasher729 Where was that? If really it takes an exercise to see you, in most of Europe nothing is gona happen, I suppose. It can only be public nuisance if you're visible from public places unexpectedly.

Comment: What about only from the pavement on the far side of the street and on double decker buses driving by from the upper deck?

Comment: That's a thought call, but I would say not public enough. But I'm not a judge.

Comment: What would you say if neighbours could easily see you, even unintentionally, from their own private balconies?

Comment: @PMF Exactly. Her neighbour complained, someone checked, the complaint was rejected, and everyone else laughed about the stupidity of it all.

Comment: But where was this?